# Bash upgrade on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, bash

So, I followed [this tutorial](http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2009/03/upgrade-bash-to-40-in-mac-os-x.html)...

It seems that it worked fine. When I type in

`echo $SHELL and echo $BASH_VERSION`

I get

`"/usr/local/bin/bash" and "4.0.0(1)-release`" .

But, when I simply run "`bash`" I get shells command line with "`bash-3.2$`" (not sure if this is important?) and when I try to install RVM (which is my main reason for doing the upgrade in the first place) I still get the

```
BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.2.17(1)-release)
```

error.

Comment: Your installation of OS X is quite old, isn't it? On 10.6.8, `/bin/bash` has the version `3.2.48(1)-release`. Anyway, the tutorial you linked to was written 3 years ago, and the latest release of Bash is [4.2.37](ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz). You may want to install that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `/bin/bash` takes precedence over `/usr/local/bin/bash` in your $PATH. Thus, when you simply write `bash`, it'll load the former instead of the more recent version.

To fix this, you will need to edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Save the file, and reload your shell (e.g. by exiting the Terminal). Now, any call to `bash` should use the version in `/usr/local/bin` instead.

Comment: Here is a [documentation](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284351#284351) about the PATH variable, at the end OS X is discussed. You can also edit `/etc/paths` (provided you have administrator rights) and put the line */usr/local/bin* above the line */bin* so that the binaries in `/usr/local/bin` have precedence.

Comment: That's true, but I'd personally rather not change system files for these kinds of per-user tasks.